# DataTables requested unknown parameter nested object

Tags: jquery, datatables

Table creation;

```
var table = $("#tbl-inventory-report").DataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: "/api/inventory",
        dataSrc: "",
    },
    "oLanguage": {
        "sProcessing": ""
    },
    processing: true,
    columns: [
        {
            data: "Id",
            className: "visible-lg",
        },
        {
            data: "Employee.LogonName"
        }
     ]
});
```

Example Json Result of Ajax Request;

```
{  
   Id:3434,
   Employee:{  
      Id:10,
      LogonName:"Example10"
   }
}
```

JS Code that I get the error;

```
table.row.add({
     "Id": 11,     
     "Employee.LogonName": "Example11",         
}
```

Data loads successfully when page loaded. However, when I want to add rows later on, I get the following error. Any Idea?

Requested unknown parameter 'Employee.LogonName' for row 2856, column 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the record structure defined in your inventory api, you need to change this line:

```
table.row.add({
    "Id": 11,     
    "Employee.LogonName": "Example11",         
}
```

to:

```
table.row.add({
    "Id": 11,
    "Employee": {
        "LogonName": "Example11"
    }
});
```